# Difference between vmlinuz-2.6.32-34-generic and vmlinuz-2.6.32-34-generic-pae

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, i386

Can someone please tell me the difference between these two vmlinuz images ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The PAE kernel includes [Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Linux).  This increases the usable memory from 4 GB to 64 GB. The cost is that these kernels take up a little more memory and don't run on some old processors.